# Alternate formula of Archimedean property

Tags: real-analysis

In Chapter 1 of Royden's real analysis textbook, he states:

> We frequently use the Archimedean property of $\mathbf{R}$ reformulated as follows; for each positive real number $\epsilon$, there is a natural number $n$ for which $\frac{1}{n} < \epsilon^2$.

I am trying to demonstrate how this follows from (though it does not seem to be equivalent to) the standard definition of the Archimedean property, which states that
$$\forall x, y \in \mathbb{R}^+, \; \exists n \in \mathbb{N}, \; nx > y.$$
Here is my best attempt.

> I will first work in the direction of the usual formulation to Royden's alernate formulation. I can certainly work with $\epsilon$ in place of $x$ and $y$. The reformulation is
>   $$\forall \epsilon > 0, \; \exists n \in \mathbb{N}, \; n \epsilon > \epsilon.$$
>   Taking repricols: 
>   $$\frac{1}{n \epsilon} < \frac{1}{\epsilon}.$$
>   If I multiply through by $\epsilon$, I get $\frac{1}{n} < 1$. Furthermore, I cannot say that $\frac{1}{\epsilon} < \frac{1}{\epsilon^2}$ because we could have $\epsilon \in (0,1)$, in which case the opposite is true.

It seems to me that Royden's alternate formulation is not equivalent to the first formulation, which can work when $x \neq y$. Then again, I could be doing something wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you really mean "$\forall \varepsilon > 0, \exists n \in \mathbb{N}, n\varepsilon > \varepsilon$"?  Isn't that true if $\varepsilon \in \mathbb{N}$?  But $\mathbb{N}$ isn't Archimedean...

Comment: Hm, I think you're right. All I did was set $x = y = \epsilon$. Was this an incorrect jump?

Answer (score 2):

Assume that

$$\forall \epsilon>0 \;\;\exists n>0 \;:\;\frac 1n<\epsilon$$

Let $(x,y)\in \Bbb R^{+2}$.

If we put $\epsilon=\frac xy$, then

$$\exists n>0 \; : \; \frac 1n <\frac xy$$
or $$nx>y$$

Now, assume that

$$\forall (x,y)\in \Bbb R^{+2} \;\; \exists n>0 \; :\; nx>y$$

then, you can take $$x=\epsilon \text{ and } y=1$$
to get

$$\forall \epsilon>0 \;\; \exists n>0 \;\; : \;\; \frac 1n<\epsilon$$

Both formulations are equivalent.

Comment: This proof makes sense. Does it not matter whether we write it as $\epsilon$ or $\epsilon^2$ (since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary)?

Comment: Also, would I be correct that all of the steps here are reversible? Since we can define $\frac{x}{y} =: \epsilon$, and since $x$ and $y$ are arbitrary, $\epsilon$ is also arbitrary?